# update two or more tables with the single statement

Tags: sql

How do i update two or more two tables without the help of where clause.

Thanks...

Comment: Could you please describe your problem. What you want to achieve. Why using single statement.

Comment: Which RDBMS? Solutions can depend on the type of database engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using an **updateable view** and **instead of trigger**.

For this you need to create a view on your base tables and add an "instead of" trigger to this view

Later you can update the view directly.

For more information check the following links

[how to update multiple tables in oracle DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966546/how-to-update-multiple-tables-in-oracle-db)

[Update multiple table column values using single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695116/update-multiple-table-column-values-using-single-query)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you cannot update two tables in one update statement even in an updateable view.